# Does the vtable persist among binaries if using a non-common class?

Tags: c++, linker, vtable

Say I have three libraries, all written in C++:

1. `logging.a`: a static library to assist with logging. It defines an abstract class that other classes can use to customize their logging (by implementing the pure virtual method `virtual void CustomLogger::customLogging(std::string) = 0`).
2. `libmainproject.so`: the main library. It contains a class, unknown to the outside, (`CustomLoggerImpl`) which extends `CustomLogger` and implements the custom logging method.
3. `libplugin.so`: a plugin library which needs to log stuff and wants to integrate its logging with the one in `libmainproject`.

The interface between `libmainproject` and `libplugin` is a C interface, despite the internals of both libraries being written in C++.

`libplugin` has no idea of the existence of `CustomLoggerImpl` inside `libmainproject`, but does know about the interface `CustomLogger` from `logging`.

In order to use the custom logging from `libplugin` I have passed a pointer to `CustomLoggerImpl` as `void *` (because it happens over a C interface, can't use custom objects).

Once I need to log inside the plugin, I cast the `void *` (which points to a `CustomLoggerImpl` object) into a `CustomLogger *` (Liskov substitution principle). Then I invoke `customLogger->customLogging("whatever");`.

**Although nothing crashes, the call doesn't seem to make it to `libmainproject`. Why is that?** I assume the issue is that there is some issue with the vtable, so that it doesn't work properly from a different binary which doesn't have the definition of the object, but would like some more in-depth explanation of why this might be happening.

Comment: Cast of `void *` pointing to `CustomLoggerImpl` object to pointer to `CustomLogger` may be invalid depending on  `CustomLoggerImpl` implementation. Those types are not necessary pointer-interconvertible.  But it is not possible to tell exactly what is going on since you didn't provide [mcve].

Comment: If the libraries are built with different compilers/settings, there can be incompatibilities.   Even if built with compatible library/settings there are always issues when non-trivial C++ classes cross runtime (dll or .so) boundaries.   Based on the information you have provided, there are many possibilities and anyone trying to help will be resorting to guesswork.  You'll need to give more detailed information (and preferably produce a [mcve]) to get useful advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynamically-linked (shared) libraries are not defined by Standard C++, so you're in implementation-specific behavior.

Implementations generally do reasonable things; it would be reasonable to assume that `CustomLogger` has the same `vtable` layout in all binaries. The Standard doesn't even prescribe a vtable, so this is not a hard statement.

Implementations that support dynamically-linked libraries generally do not assume that all code lives in a single binary. On Windows, MSVC makes less assumptions because it has an `__declspec(dllimport)` extension that tells the compiler specifically that there's code coming from another binary. But your question makes it clear you're not using MSVC. Your compiler is not going to assume that a `customLogging` override has to be defined in `libplugin.so`, just because `libplugin.so` calls `customLogging`.

Hence, I'm going to agree with VTT. The biggest issue here seems to be that you're casting a `CustomLoggerImpl*` to `CustomLogger*` via `void*`, where it should have been 
`CustomLoggerImpl* -> CustomLogger* -> void* -> CustomLogger*`. The conversion to base class should happen explicitly, in C++ code.

Comment: "_Dynamically-linked (shared) libraries are not defined by Standard C++_" Neither are statically linked (true) libraries...

Comment: @curiousguy: The standard does say that the linker phase combines translation units. Bundling those TU's in a static library does not materially affect that. After all, the standard doesn't define object files either.

Comment: Then runtime linking does not materially affect it either.